# Error was: cannot import name 'GDALRaster' on Windows 10 for GeoDjango

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango, postgis-installation

I am trying to follow GeoDjango Tutorial . I am using a windows-10 64bit computer. and I am using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11 I followed the  [GeoDjango Windows Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows)  to install. I have successfully completed all the steps it told me to I also downloaded and ran OSGeo4W and successfully ran the paths in my cmd.exe as administrator

[image]

Now getting back to the **[Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geodjango-tutorial)**

[Create a Spatial Database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#create-a-spatial-database): I made a Database in my Postgres Sql

[image]

I started a Django project called **geodjango**, Started a app called **world**

I changed the database in the setting to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'geodjango',
         'USER': 'geo',
    },
}
```

I added the below in my settings.py installed apps apps

```
'django.contrib.gis',
'world',
```

I made a directory called data in the `world` application. I downloaded the zip file and unzipped it in my data folder. I have the below files in my data folder
[image]

[Use ogrinfo to examine spatial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#use-ogrinfo-to-examine-spatial-data)(I dint know what to do here, So I ignored this part)

I successfully made the **models.py** like it says in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#defining-a-geographic-model)

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Then the tutorial asks me to run python manage.py makemigrations when I do that I get the below error

```
Error was: cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
```

**What can I do to fix this error**

I tried

```
pip install gdal
```

that gave me a error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

so I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. and tried to run

```
 pip install gdal
```

again Now I get the error

```
`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit statu
s 2`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying almost everything. I moved my os from windows to Linux with Ubuntu 18 (Udemy course to learn Ubuntu) through virtual box then simply did

sudo apt install geos
sudo apt install prog4
sudo apt install gdal

installed postgres sql and pgadmin3 (pg admin 4 is not available easily for install as of today on ubuntu ) made the database on called 'geodjango' using pgadmin3 then
sudo apt install postgis

then pip installed
psycopg2  and
dj-database-url

I would recommend to stay away from the make & make install methods they take too long and always throws errors. After this the [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geodjango-tutorial) was a breeze